# Magento 2 Best way to merge specific DB tables and data from one database to another

Tags: database, sales-order, data-migration

We have two enviroments Staging and Production, for Magento 2.3.5. At the moment these two enviroments have different database structure, meaning that we can't just dump the entire DB and restore it to the other enviroment. We need to merge **Orders**, **products**,**customers** from one DB to another. I have thought of the following 3 options.

1. Use Magento 2 default ***import / export function*** to export orders, products and customers then import to another enviroment
2. ***dump all relavant mysql tables*** for orders, products and customers and restore them to another enviroment
3. write an ***custom module***, something like using ***Magento's resrouce model***, to transfer orders, products and customers to another enviroment

which one of the above option would you suggest? are there any other better way to do it?

Comment: Does Magento (CE) provide a default import/export function to export orders? how? Please help me to figure out that

Comment: And I curious to know how you have managed to complete this task? Please let me know how you have managed to achieve this. Thanks

Comment: @NileshDubey I haven't done it yet. but I will consider using the Magento default import / export  under admin -> system -> Data Transfer, if you ever managed to try this out, please let me know how it goes :)

Comment: No for me I haven't got the option to import/Export for Orders. Please share your knowledge because this will surely help me in future

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely opt for the first option

> Use Magento 2 default import / export function to export orders, products and customers then import to another environment

Why do so? Because Magento will manage all entity dependencies and you won't have to be concerned with handling foreign keys, list of tables, mappings and error treating.

You just need to make sure that all relevant attributes and columns exist in the destination database.

Comment: Seems I can only Export Products and Customers by using Magentos default Import / Export functions. There's no option to Export Orders.

Comment: yes, unfortunately, that's true. however, there are some extensions on the marketplace which might help you. i haven't tried any of them yet, but if i would need to do this task, i would do it.